# STM32F446E doesn't show raw image on FT801 Display

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, ftdi, hal

I'm working on a STM32F446E connected to a FTDI FT801 LCD. I am stacked on the commands communication on the SPI between the Micro and the LCD Controller. I have to load a couple of images on the LCD but I didn't found a proper guide on the net. There are a lot of guides for what concern the LCD controller, the ones that I have read don't explain anything about the right sequence of instructions to invoke on the micro.

I wrote the new following function in order to store the raw bytes into the graphic RAM of the FTDI co-processor. I've done the following steps:

- Mount the SD Card where the raw file is actually stored;
- Open the raw file;
- Execute N times the first loop in order to send to the CMD buffer the raw data, up to the end of the raw file (I'm using CMD_MEMWRITE);
- Once all the image bytes are sent to the graphic RAM, I'm actually checking that the data written on the RAM are equal to the data read from the raw file. The interesting thing is that they seems to be equal, and therefore it makes me think that they are written correctly in the previous step. In addition, since the dimension of the file is 20400 Bytes I'm also checking that the number of Bytes written is equal to this amount and it actually is.
- At the end, I display the bitmap stored starting from the graphic RAM address 0x000000. Here is the trouble, no bitmap is displayed! I tried to put this last part on top of the data writing procedure and it actually displays a bitmap (with random colours).

I hope that someone already had the same problem because I really don't know what to do in order to solve this issue. Does anyone have some idea?

Thanks for your time!

Anna

```
void Load_Image_From_SD3() {
   FATFS SDFatFs;
   char SDPath[4];
   FIL MyFile_R; /* File object */
   uint8_t data[4];
   uint32_t data32;
   uint32_t bytesread; /* File read counts */
   uint32_t filesize;
   uint16_t blocklen;
   uint32_t image_width = 100;
   uint32_t image_height = 102;
   int32_t count;
   int16_t num_bytes;
   uint32_t check=0;
   uint32_t n=0;

   char buffer1[10];
   uint8_t CURRENTDIR1[40];

   char buffer[5];
   uint8_t CURRENTDIR[40];

   uint32_t length = 0, SizeTransfered = 0;
   uint16_t availablefreesize;

   uint8_t value1c, value2c, value3c, value4c;
   uint32_t data_readc;
   uint8_t check_wrong = 0;
   uint32_t index_ram = 0x000000;
   FIL MyFile_R2;

   /* Link the SD disk I/O driver */
   if (BSP_SD_Init() == 0) {
        if (FATFS_LinkDriver(&SD_Driver, SDPath) == 0) {
             /*## Register the file system object to the FatFs module ##############*/
             if (f_mount(&SDFatFs, (TCHAR const*) SDPath, 0) != FR_OK) {
                  /* FatFs Initialization Error */
                  Address_RAM_DL = 0x900000;
                  SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x26000007, 7); // CLEAR
                  SPI_Send_String("Cannot mount the SD", 19, 1, 27,
                  Color_RGB(0, 0, 255));
                  SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x00000000, 7); // DISPLAY
                  SPI_Send(0x902450, 0x02, 4); // REG_DLSWAP
                  HAL_Delay(1000);
             } else {
                  FRESULT res_jpg = f_open(&MyFile_R, "usbg7.raw", FA_OPEN_EXISTING | FA_READ);
                  filesize =(uint32_t)(MyFile_R.fsize);
                  uint32_t address = 0x10000000;
                  //Writing raw image into RAM_G
                  while(filesize > 0){
                          blocklen = filesize > 2000 ? 2000 : filesize;
                          filesize -= blocklen;
                          Ft_Gpu_Hal_WaitCmdfifo_empty();
                          Address_RAM_CMD = 0x908000;
                          SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, 0xFFFFFF00, 7);// DLSTART
                          SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, 0x26000007, 7); // CLEAR
                          SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, 0xffffff1a, 7); // CMD_MEMWRITE
                          SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, address, 7); // Destination starting address in Graphics RAM
                          SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, (uint32_t)blocklen, 7);
                          count = blocklen;
                          do{
                               length = count;
                               availablefreesize = Ft_Gpu_Cmdfifo_Freespace();
                               if (length > availablefreesize) {
                                    length = availablefreesize;
                               }
                               num_bytes = length;
                               while (num_bytes > 0) {
                                    f_read(&MyFile_R, data, sizeof(data), (UINT*) &bytesread);
                                    data32 = ((uint32_t) data[3] << 24 + ((uint32_t) data[2] << 16) + ((uint32_t) data[1] << 8)  + (uint32_t) data[0];
                                    SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, data32, 7);
                                    n += 4;
                                    SizeTransfered += 4;
                                    address += 4;
                                    num_bytes -= 4;
                               }
                               SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, 7);
                               length = SizeTransfered;
                               count -= length;
                               SPI_Send(0x9024E8, (uint16_t) (ft_cmd_fifo_wp),  7);
                               Ft_Gpu_Hal_WaitCmdfifo_empty();
                          } while (count > 0);
                          HAL_Delay(800);
                  }
                 // Check if the data written are correct
                  f_close(&MyFile_R);
                  f_open(&MyFile_R2, "usbg7.raw", FA_OPEN_EXISTING | FA_READ);
                  filesize = (uint32_t) (MyFile_R2.fsize);
                  do {
                       f_read(&MyFile_R2, data, sizeof(data), (UINT*) &bytesread);
                       data32 = ((uint32_t) data[3] << 24) + ((uint32_t) data[2] << 16) + ((uint32_t) data[1] << 8) + (uint32_t) data[0];
                       value1c = SPI_Receive_8(index_ram);
                       value2c = SPI_Receive_8(index_ram + 1);
                       value3c = SPI_Receive_8(index_ram + 2);
                       value4c = SPI_Receive_8(index_ram + 3);
                       index_ram += 4;
                       filesize -= 4;
                       data_readc = ((uint32_t) value4c << 24) + ((uint32_t) value3c << 16) + ((uint32_t) value2c << 8) + (uint32_t) value1c;
                       if (data32 != data_readc)
                            check_wrong = 1;
                  } while (check_wrong == 0 && filesize>0);
                  f_close(&MyFile_R2);
                  if (check_wrong) {
                       char bufferw[10];
                       uint8_t CURRENTDIRw[40];
                       itoa(index_ram - 4, bufferw, 16);
                       for (int k = 0; k < strlen(bufferw); k++) {
                            CURRENTDIRw[k] = bufferw[k];
                       }
                       Address_RAM_DL = 0x900000;
                       SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x26000007, 7); // CLEAR
                       SPI_Send_String("wrong data at index:", 19, 3, 16,
                       Color_RGB(255, 255, 255));
                       SPI_Send_String(CURRENTDIRw, strlen(bufferw), 8, 16, Color_RGB(255, 255, 255));
                       SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x00000000, 7); // DISPLAY
                       SPI_Send(0x902450, 0x02, 4); // REG_DLSWAP
                       HAL_Delay(1000);
                       itoa(data_readc, buffer, 16);
                       for (int k = 0; k < strlen(buffer); k++){
                            CURRENTDIR[k] = buffer[k];
                       }
                       Address_RAM_DL = 0x900000;
                       SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x26000007, 7); // CLEAR
                       SPI_Send_String("value read:", 11, 3, 16,Color_RGB(255, 255, 255));
                       SPI_Send_String(CURRENTDIR, strlen(buffer), 8, 16,(255, 255, 255));
                       SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x00000000, 7); // DISPLAY
                       SPI_Send(0x902450, 0x02, 4); // REG_DLSWAP
                       HAL_Delay(1000);

                       itoa(data32, buffer1, 16);
                       for (int k = 0; k < strlen(buffer1); k++) {
                            CURRENTDIR1[k] = buffer1[k];
                       }
                       Address_RAM_DL = 0x900000;
                       SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x26000007, 7); // CLEAR
                       SPI_Send_String("value sent:", 11, 3, 16, Color_RGB(255, 255, 255));
                       SPI_Send_String(CURRENTDIR1, strlen(buffer1), 8, 16, Color_RGB(255, 255, 255));
                       SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x00000000, 7); // DISPLAY
                       SPI_Send(0x902450, 0x02, 4); // REG_DLSWAP
                       HAL_Delay(1000);
                  }
                  else if(check_wrong == 0){
                       Address_RAM_DL = 0x900000;
                       SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x26000007, 7); // CLEAR
                       SPI_Send_String("ALL DATA CORRECT!", 17, 7, 16, Color_RGB(255, 255, 255));
                       SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x00000000, 7); // DISPLAY
                       SPI_Send(0x902450, 0x02, 4); // REG_DLSWAP
                       HAL_Delay(1000);
                  } 
                  //Show the bitmap
                  Ft_Gpu_Hal_WaitCmdfifo_empty();
                  Address_RAM_CMD = 0x908000;
                  SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, 0xFFFFFF00, 7); // DLSTART
                  SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, 0x26000007, 7); // CLEAR
                  SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, 0x1F000001,7); // BEGIN BITMAPS
                  SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, BITMAP_SOURCE(0x00000000), 7);
                  SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, BITMAP_LAYOUT( 0x07, 200, 102), 7);
                  SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, BITMAP_SIZE(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, image_width, image_height),7);
                  SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, VERTEX2II(189, 83, 0, 0), 7);
                  SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, 0x21000000,7); // END
                  SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, 0x00000000,7); // DISPLAY
                  SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(Address_RAM_CMD + ft_cmd_fifo_wp, 0xFFFFFF01,7); // SWAP
                 SPI_Send(0x9024E8, (uint16_t) (ft_cmd_fifo_wp), 7); // REG_CMD_WRITE
                  Ft_Gpu_Hal_WaitCmdfifo_empty();
                  HAL_Delay(1000);                   
            }
            f_mount(0, (TCHAR const*) SDPath, 0);
       } else{
            Address_RAM_DL = 0x900000;
            SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x26000007, 7); // CLEAR
            SPI_Send_String("Cannot Link the SD Key I/O driver", 33, 1, 27, Color_RGB(0, 0, 255));
            SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x00000000, 7); // DISPLAY
            SPI_Send(0x902450, 0x02, 4); // REG_DLSWAP
            HAL_Delay(1000);
       }
        FATFS_UnLinkDriver(SDPath);
   } else {
        Address_RAM_DL = 0x900000;
        SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x26000007, 7); // CLEAR
        SPI_Send_String("Cannot Init SD", 14, 1, 27, Color_RGB(0, 0, 255));
        SPI_Send_RAM_DL(Address_RAM_DL, 0x00000000, 7); // DISPLAY
        SPI_Send(0x902450, 0x02, 4); // REG_DLSWAP
        HAL_Delay(1000);
   }
```

}

Where:

```
void SPI_Send_RAM_CMD2(uint32_t Address, uint32_t Data, uint16_t Size)
{
   uint8_t buffer[7];
   buffer[0] = ((Address >> 16) & 0xFF);
   buffer[1] = ((Address >> 8) & 0xFF);
   buffer[2] = (Address & 0xFF);
   buffer[3] = (Data & 0xFF);
   buffer[4] = ((Data >> 8) & 0xFF);
   buffer[5] = ((Data >> 16) & 0xFF);
   buffer[6] = ((Data >> 24) & 0xFF);

   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
   HAL_SPI_Transmit(&spi_handle_structure, buffer, Size, 10000);
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);
   ft_cmd_fifo_wp = ft_Inc_CMD_Offset(ft_cmd_fifo_wp, 4);
}

uint16_t ft_Inc_CMD_Offset(uint16_t currentOffset, uint8_t commandSize)
{
   uint16_t newOffset;                         
   newOffset = currentOffset + commandSize;           
   if (newOffset > 4095) {                 // If new offset past boundary...
      newOffset = (newOffset - 4096);                 // ... roll over pointer
   }
   return newOffset;                                      
}

void SPI_Send(uint32_t Address, uint32_t Data, uint16_t Size)
{
   uint8_t buffer[7];
   buffer[0] = ((Address >> 16) & 0xFF);
   buffer[1] = ((Address >> 8) & 0xFF);
   buffer[2] = (Address & 0xFF);
   buffer[3] = (Data & 0xFF);
   buffer[4] = ((Data >> 8) & 0xFF);
   buffer[5] = ((Data >> 16) & 0xFF);
   buffer[6] = ((Data >> 24) & 0xFF);

   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
   HAL_SPI_Transmit(&spi_handle_structure, buffer, Size, 10000);
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

Comment: Thumb rule for FTDI display drivers: All instructions and data should be multiple of 4

Comment: They are indeed multiple of four: the data are sent by chunks of 4B (data32 variable) and also the commands satisfy this condition. I tried to put the bitmap display instructions above the writing procedure and a random content bitmap is displayed on the LCD (since the ram content is random if not written). Can you give me more details? Is there any instruction in my code which in your opinion doesn't satisfy the 4B condition? Thanks.